# Bootstrap form with error text

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have tried lots of way but couldn't find any solution i don't understand what is best way to fix it. Whenever I put error text first input 3rd input automatically go in the place of second input right area. I have attached screenshot.

**HTML**

```html
<form class="row bl-row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 bl-col">
    <div class="form-group has-error has-feedback nm">
      <label class="custom_lebel">First Name *</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control cfc" placeholder="Write here your name...">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></i>
      <span class="help-block">Please fill out this field.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 bl-col">
    <div class="form-group has-error has-feedback nm">
      <label class="custom_lebel">Last Name *</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control cfc" placeholder="Write here your name...">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></i>
      <span class="help-block">Please fill out this field.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 bl-col">
    <div class="form-group has-error has-feedback nm">
      <label class="custom_lebel">Username *</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control cfc" placeholder="Write here your name...">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></i>
      <span class="help-block">Please fill out this field.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 bl-col">
    <div class="form-group has-error has-feedback nm">
      <label class="custom_lebel">Email *</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control cfc" placeholder="Write here your name...">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></i>
      <span class="help-block">Please fill out this field.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here `bl-row` or `bl-col` class just for customize padding for row and col.

This is normal input field without any error here is everything normal but after error.

**Normal without any error**

[image]

This is has-error input field with error text here you can see how username input go to with last name field.

**With Error**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add classes **first** and **last**

```html
<form class="row bl-row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 bl-col first">
    <div class="form-group has-error has-feedback nm">
      <label class="custom_lebel">First Name *</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control cfc" placeholder="Write here your name...">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></i>
      <span class="help-block">Please fill out this field.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 bl-col last">
    <div class="form-group has-error has-feedback nm">
      <label class="custom_lebel">Last Name *</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control cfc" placeholder="Write here your name...">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></i>
      <span class="help-block">Please fill out this field.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 bl-col first">
    <div class="form-group has-error has-feedback nm">
      <label class="custom_lebel">Username *</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control cfc" placeholder="Write here your name...">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></i>
      <span class="help-block">Please fill out this field.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 bl-col last">
    <div class="form-group has-error has-feedback nm">
      <label class="custom_lebel">Email *</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control cfc" placeholder="Write here your name...">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></i>
      <span class="help-block">Please fill out this field.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: i have add first and last class didn't get any solution bootstrap don't have any first and last class..

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution:

```
<form>
<div  class="row bl-row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 bl-col">
    <div class="form-group has-error has-feedback nm">
      <label class="custom_lebel">First Name *</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control cfc" placeholder="Write here your name...">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></i>
      <span class="help-block">Please fill out this field.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 bl-col">
    <div class="form-group has-error has-feedback nm">
      <label class="custom_lebel">Last Name *</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control cfc" placeholder="Write here your name...">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></i>
      <span class="help-block">Please fill out this field.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div  class="row bl-row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 bl-col">
    <div class="form-group has-error has-feedback nm">
      <label class="custom_lebel">Username *</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control cfc" placeholder="Write here your name...">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></i>
      <span class="help-block">Please fill out this field.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 bl-col">
    <div class="form-group has-error has-feedback nm">
      <label class="custom_lebel">Email *</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control cfc" placeholder="Write here your name...">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></i>
      <span class="help-block">Please fill out this field.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please explain the modification you made to the OP's code.

Comment: I have just added row class